# NetBeans New Project doesn't include JavaFX folder

Tags: java, javafx-8, netbeans-8, new-project, jdk1.8-73

I am currently using NetBeans 8.1 with JDK 8 (which includes JavaFX 8) and it works fine alltogether but I can't really create JavaFX project because there is no folder like JavaFX in New Project window. The only thing is "JavaFX Application" in Maven folder which I'm not interested in.

What can be done about it?

Comment: look at tools->plugins->installed and search 'fx', see what's installed.  I have a javaFX 2.0 plugin that probably provides this functionality.  There's 3 in total for me, webview, the fx 2, and scene builder.

Comment: thx, everything's fine now ;)

Comment: You could answer your own question with details of how this happened and how you fixed it.  It might help others and even get you some votes.